# How to call a user defined function in a while loop in Python

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I defined this function:

```
def formatted_name(firstName, lastName, middleName=''):
    if middleName:
        full_name = f"{firstName} {lastName} {middleName}"
    else:
        full_name = f"{firstName} {lastName}"
    return full_name.title()
```

and then tried to use it like so:

```
prompt = 'Please enter your first and last name below'
prompt += '\nEnter stop to quit'
quit = 'stop'
while not quit:
    print(prompt)
    firstname = input('Enter your first name: ')
    lastname = input('Enter your last name: ')
    if firstname == quit:
        break
fullName = formatted_name(firstname,lastname)
print(fullName)
```

When I try this, I get a `NameError`. What is wrong with the code, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you define the function before, or after, the code that calls it?  After does you no good.

Comment: I declared it before

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `while not quit:`, what do you expect that to mean? Will the condition be satisfied the first time the code reaches this point? Why?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are not interested in conversational language or discussion of your skill level, attitude towards learning etc.; but only in clear, specific questions. I [edit]ed the question to show how it's done. In the future, though, please try to show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that firstname and lastname are not defined. It never executes the code inside your while loop because when you convert a string that is not empty to a bool which in this case is "stop" you get True, since you have "not quit" in your while loop then it Will never execute because not quit is False. A while loop with False in it never executes the code inside

```
>>> bool("stop")
True
>>> not bool("stop")
False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and try to write answers in proper English sentences, without slang such as "ur".

Answer (score 0):

In python, every string except empty string (`''`  and `""`) are considered `True`. The codition `not quit`, evaluates to `not True`, evaluates to `False`. So the while loop, does not runs.

You are getting `NameError`, because, `firstName` are `lastName` are not declared, till running the statement `fullName = formatted_name(firstname,lastname)`.

The correct version of the above code is:

```
def formatted_name(firstName, lastName, middleName=''):
    if middleName:
         full_name = f"{firstName} {lastName} {middleName}"
    else:
         full_name = f"{firstName} {lastName}"
    return full_name.title()


prompt = 'Please enter your first and last name below'
prompt += '\nEnter stop to quit'
quit = 'stop'
while True:
    print(prompt)
    firstname = input('Enter your first name: ')
    if firstname == quit:
        break
    lastname = input('Enter your last name: ')
    fullName = formatted_name(firstname,lastname)
    print(fullName)
```